# SQL BigQuery Combining results from two queries with spatial joins

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, geospatial, spatial-query

I am interested in the NYC zip codes in which the most taxi pickups per Citi Bike station occur. The following two queries return the zip codes with the most Citi Bike stations:

```
SELECT
    zip_code AS zip,
    COUNT(*) AS bike_stations
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` AS bike_stations,
    `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` AS zip_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
         zip_codes.zip_code_geom,
         ST_GeogPoint(bike_stations.longitude, bike_stations.latitude),
         500)
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY bike_stations DESC
```

and the zip codes with the most taxi pickups:

```
SELECT 
  zip_codes.zip_code,
  COUNT(taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude) as taxi_pickups_per_station, 
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_2015` AS taxi_trips_coordinates TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (5 PERCENT), 
  `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` AS zip_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  zip_codes.zip_code_geom,
  ST_GeogPoint(taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_longitude, taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude),
  500) 
  AND
  (taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_longitude >= -90 AND taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude <= 90) #drops incorrect longitude and latitude       
GROUP BY zip_codes.zip_code
ORDER BY taxi_pickups_per_station DESC
```

(I added TABLESAMPLE to keep the computational load manageable).

My question is: How can I combine both queries to obtain the zip codes with most taxi pickups per Citi Bike station?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    zip_codes.zip_code,
    COUNT(taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude)/COUNT(station_coordinates.station_id) as nr_taxi_pickups_per_station 
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_2015` AS taxi_trips_coordinates TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (0.000000001 PERCENT),
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` AS station_coordinates,
  `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` AS zip_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
         zip_codes.zip_code_geom,
         ST_GeogPoint(taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_longitude, taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude),
         500) AND 
        (taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_longitude >= -90 AND taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude <= 90) AND #drops incorrect longtitude and latitude
        ST_DWithin(
         zip_codes.zip_code_geom,
         ST_GeogPoint(station_coordinates.longitude, station_coordinates.latitude),
         500) AND (station_coordinates.longitude >= -90 AND station_coordinates.latitude <= 90)
GROUP BY zip_codes.zip_code
ORDER BY nr_taxi_pickups_per_station DESC
```

However, the computing time is gigantic. Do you have an idea how it could work better?

Answer (score 0):

Without checking the logic of this particular query, a few quick points that make a huge difference for spatial queries:

1. Create geography columns in tables (copying table if needed) beforehand instead of creating them on the fly in queries.  (Can filter bad geographies, bad lat/lons here as well.)
2. When creating these tables (with geography column), cluster on the geography column!  (This made joining a couple of tables with 100 million records each finish in a couple minutes instead of timing out after 8 hours.)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply JOIN the two tables on ZIP and compute pick ups per station:

```
WITH bike_stations AS (
  -- your first query, drop ORDER BY which is not needed here
), pickups AS (
  -- your second query, drop ORDER BY which is not needed here
)
SELECT 
    zip_code, 
    taxi_pickups_per_zip / bike_stations as taxi_pickups_per_station 
FROM bike_stations b JOIN pickups p
ON b.zip = p.zip_code
ORDER BY taxi_pickups_per_station DESC
```

Full query:

```
WITH bike_stations AS (
    SELECT
    zip_code AS zip,
    COUNT(*) AS bike_stations
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` AS bike_stations,
    `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` AS zip_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
         zip_codes.zip_code_geom,
         ST_GeogPoint(bike_stations.longitude, bike_stations.latitude),
         500)
GROUP BY zip
), pickups AS (

SELECT 
  zip_codes.zip_code,
  COUNT(taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude) as taxi_pickups_per_zip, 
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_2015` AS taxi_trips_coordinates TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (5 PERCENT), 
  `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes` AS zip_codes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  zip_codes.zip_code_geom,
  ST_GeogPoint(taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_longitude, taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude),
  500) 
  AND
  (taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_longitude >= -90 AND taxi_trips_coordinates.pickup_latitude <= 90) #drops incorrect longitude and latitude       
GROUP BY zip_codes.zip_code
)
SELECT 
    zip_code, 
    taxi_pickups_per_zip / bike_stations as taxi_pickups_per_station 
FROM bike_stations b JOIN pickups p
ON b.zip = p.zip_code
ORDER BY taxi_pickups_per_station DESC
```

Note you might have an issue here if some zip code contains taxi pickups, but no bikes. Its pickups per station is infinite - since you would divide by zero stations. But this query drops such zip codes completely.